# React: Refresh component without reload after deleting an item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my React App, I'm displaying all the books with author name. User can delete a book by clicking an item. Thing is I want to refresh the page without reloading the entire page. States are the way to go for such kind of situations but it still doesn't refresh the component.

Can anybody suggest any ideas?

App.tsx

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAllBooks } from "./api_actions/api_calls";
import "./App.css";
import AllBooks from "./components/AllBooks";
import InsertBooks from "./components/InsertBook";
import { Book } from "./models/Book";

function App() {
    const [myBooks, setMyBooks] = useState<Book[]>([]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        getAllBooks().then((orders) => {
            setMyBooks(orders);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<AllBooks books={myBooks} />} />
                        <Route path="/add" element={<InsertBooks />} />
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Component that displays all the books, AllBooks.tsx:

```
interface IAllBooksProps {
    books: Book[];
}

const AllBooks: React.FC<IAllBooksProps> = (props) => {
    const [lastDeletedTitle, setLastDeletedTitle] = useState("");
    const handleDeleteBook = (title: string) => {
        console.log("Trying to delete...", title);

        deleteBook(title).then((response) => {
            setLastDeletedTitle(title);
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (lastDeletedTitle !== "") {
            toast(`${lastDeletedTitle}  has been deleted!`);
        }
    }, [lastDeletedTitle]);

    return (
        <>
            {props.books?.map((book) => {
                return <Card key={book.id} book={book} onDelete={handleDeleteBook} />;
            })}
            <ToastContainer />
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring changes in AllBooks.tsx like below.

```
const AllBooks: React.FC<IAllBooksProps> = (props) => {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState(props.books); //props.books set in books state
    const [lastDeletedTitle, setLastDeletedTitle] = useState("");

    const handleDeleteBook = (title: string) => {
        console.log("Trying to delete...", title);

        deleteBook(title).then((response) => {
            setLastDeletedTitle(title);
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (lastDeletedTitle !== "") {

           toast(`${lastDeletedTitle}  has been deleted!`);
           //recall the getAllBooks here
           getAllBooks().then((orders) => {
             setBooks(orders); //reset books
           });

        }
    }, [lastDeletedTitle]);


    
    return (
        <>
            //return books here 
            {books?.map((book) => {
                return <Card key={book.id} book={book} onDelete={handleDeleteBook} />;
            })}
            <ToastContainer />
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to call `getAllBooks` in `App.tsx`. You just need to call `getAllBooks` inside your `delete` function and `useEffect` in `AllBooks.tsx`. Try the code given below,

AllBooks.tsx

```
interface IAllBooksProps {
    books: Book[];
}

const AllBooks: React.FC<IAllBooksProps> = (props) => {
    const [lastDeletedTitle, setLastDeletedTitle] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
      getBooks();
    }, [])
    const getBooks = () => {
      getAllBooks().then((orders) => {
        setMyBooks(orders);
      });
    }
    const handleDeleteBook = (title: string) => {
        console.log("Trying to delete...", title);

        deleteBook(title).then((response) => {
            setLastDeletedTitle(title);
            getBooks();
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (lastDeletedTitle !== "") {
            toast(`${lastDeletedTitle}  has been deleted!`);
        }
    }, [lastDeletedTitle]);

    return (
        <>
            {props.books?.map((book) => {
                return <Card key={book.id} book={book} onDelete={handleDeleteBook} />;
            })}
            <ToastContainer />
        </>
    );
};
```